# updating the column values by performing the rounding function

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Need help for the below scenario :

I have a column quantity in 1 table , where the values in the column quantity are

```
Quantity
234.8735 |
43.7611  |
477.654  |
```

I want to update each record by performing 2 digit round function . so that the output must be

```
Quantity
234.87  |
43.76   |
477.65  |
```

Comment: Is it related to Oracle? Please tag accordingly

Comment: I'm going to vote against your suggestion.  Just leave your numeric data as is, and worry about precision formatting at the time you query, or even when you bring the data into your presentation layer.  Nothing wrong with a little bit of extra information, which can always be thrown away later on.

Comment: If you go ahead against Tim's advice, what is your question? You know you need to do an update with round, so what problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

You may simply check for the length of the decimal portition

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
set Quantity=round(Quantity,length(TO_CHAR(Quantity - floor(Quantity) ) ) - 3);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Does `;` must be there?